# How to Set Left and Right Brackets for Shortcut Keys

Tags: delphi

I tried this code but won't work :

```
act22.ShortCut := Menus.ShortCut(Ord('['), [ssCtrl]);
act23.ShortCut := Menus.ShortCut(Ord(']'), [ssCtrl]);
```

tried browsing **VK_*** for something like VK_LBRACKET or VK_RBRACKET on the editor but failed to find one.. I'm sure this is an easy one but already taking sometime. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the key tables in Embarcadero's documentation: [Representing Keys and Shortcuts](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Representing_Keys_and_Shortcuts). The bracket keys are listed as `vkLeftBracket` and `vkRightBracket`

Answer (score 1):

thanks for remy, here is my working code :

```
act22.ShortCut := Menus.ShortCut(System.UITypes.vkLeftBracket, [ssCtrl]);
act23.ShortCut := Menus.ShortCut(System.UITypes.vkRightBracket, [ssCtrl]);
```